# How to add header or fixed header view to listview in widget?

Tags: android, listview, widget

do you know how to add a header/fixed header to the `listview` in a collection widget? That `listview` is in a `RemoteViews`.

I mean utilize the framework's API (like `addHeaderView`), leaving me out of maintaining a header though `getCount`/`getViewAt` of the normal `RemoteAdapter`.